# scanf not reading input

Tags: c, scanf

I read more threads about scanf and I found some answers bot none helped me:

```
while(!comanda){
    int tmp;
    if (scanf("%d", &tmp) == 0)
        getchar();
    else{
        comanda = tmp;
        fprintf(stdout,"%d",&comanda);
        fflush(stdout);}
    }
}
```

The problem is that after this lines of code get executed, nothing happens. After this I have a check on "comanda" which does not execute.

Comment: `fprintf(stdout,"%d",&comanda);` - the `&` shouldn't be there. Just as a side note.

Comment: please be more specific. where does the code stop when you say "nothing happens"? where is it blocking?

Comment: Edited. Now it should make sense.

Comment: What is "comanda" equal to initially?

Comment: Initially comanda it's equal to zero. It's a problem with scanf taking the newline in the buffer or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems with `scanf` and all of the *formatted input functions* is that terminals tend to operate in [line mode or cooked mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooked_Mode#History) and the API is designed for raw mode.  In other words, `scanf` implementations generally will not return until a line feed is encountered.  The input is buffered and future calls to `scanf` will consume the buffered line.  Consider the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a_number;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (scanf("%d", &a_number) != EOF) {
        printf("you entered %d\n", a_number);
        printf("Enter another number: ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can enter multiple numbers before pressing <kbd>return</kbd>.  Here is an example of running this program.

```
bash$ gcc foo.c
bash$ ./a.out
Enter a number: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10<Return>
you entered 1
Enter another number: you entered 2
Enter another number: you entered 3
Enter another number: you entered 4
Enter another number: you entered 5
Enter another number: you entered 6
Enter another number: you entered 7
Enter another number: you entered 8
Enter another number: you entered 9
Enter another number: you entered 10
Enter another number: <Ctrl+D>bash$ 
bash$
```

Each call to `scanf` read a single number from the input stream but the first call did not return until after I pressed <kbd>return</kbd>.  The remaining calls returned immediately without blocking for more input because the input stream was buffered and it could read another integer from the stream.

The alternatives to this are to use `fgets` and processing entire lines of data at one time or using [the terminal interface](http://opengroup.org./onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html) to disable [*"canonical input processing"*](http://opengroup.org./onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_07).  Most people use `fgets` since the terminal interface section of POSIX is not implemented under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf("%d", &tmp)` can return one of 3 values

- if it returns `1` it means a value was read and placed in tmp
- if it returns `0` it means there was a bad character in buffer (which you detect and get rid of with the next `getchar()`)
- if it returns `EOF` it means `stdin` is at end-of-file condition. No matter how many `getchar()`s you do, the 'end-of-file' condition is not going away and you're stuck in an infinite loop.

Also test the return value from scanf for EOF.

```
while(!comanda){
    int tmp;
    int ret;
    ret = scanf("%d", &tmp);
    if (ret == 0)
        getchar();
    else if (ret == EOF){
        perror("stdin end-of-file");
        break; /* get out of the loop */
    }
    else {
        comanda = tmp;
        fprintf(stdout,"%d",comanda); /* & is an error */
        fflush(stdout);}
    }
}
```

Or, even **better**, redo your program to read a full line with `fgets()` and parse it with `sscanf()`.