# While loop not waiting for input with scanf("%d")

Tags: c, while-loop

I have a while loop that prints a prompt for an integer. I want to error check for when the user enters a char, like 'a'. However, when I type 'a', it prints "Enter the seed: Seed must be an integer value, please try again" forever.

```
int getSeed() {
    int scanned, seed;

    while (scanned == 0) {
       printf("Enter the seed: ");
       scanned = scanf("%d", &seed);
       if (scanned == 0) {
          printf("Seed must be an integer, try again\n");
       }
    }
    return seed;
}
```

How do I get this to print

`Enter the seed: a
 Seed must be an integer, try again
 Enter the seed:`

Thanks.

EDIT: Solved it, I added getchar(); after the scanf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf not reading input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289542/scanf-not-reading-input)

Comment: Your solution won't really solve it. Things will still go wrong if someone enters, for example "aa". If you want to read a line and then parse it, write code to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` checks your input character and finds out that it does not match the conversion specifier, so it puts it back in the input stream.
Then in your `while` loop in your code reaches to `scanf` again, and the above process occurs again (since the `a` you've written in input stream is still there)

So a better solution would be reading it as a character (or string) and then converting that into an integer.